# naming conventions / coding standards for methods in a service

Tags: coding-standards, naming-standards

At work, we are having 'arguments' about naming styles / conventions.  Imagine having a service called `UserSettingsService`. This has 2 methods, one to get the user settings and one to save.  Would you name the method to include what it does exactly, like `.getUserSettings()`, or just `get()`?

One argument is that the `UserSettings` part is implied in the service name.  The other argument is that a full method name of `getUserSettings()` is unambiguos.  Is there any 'correct' way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual convention is not to repeat the class name in the method

ie `Customer.CustomerName` == bad

In your case, `UserSettingsService` sounds like a repository, which only contains user settings. So I would have methods like:

```
UserSettingsRepository.GetById(string id)
UserSettingsRepository.GetAll()
```

etc etc

If you have more than one type of settings you might include the type:

```
SettingsRepository.GetAllUserSettings();
```

Or you might have a 'resource':

```
SettingsRepository.UserSettings.GetAll();
```

**Edit**

Another method of resolving 'arguments' about naming conventions is to organize a *Definitive Resolution in Naming Conventions Session*. These session should take place in a pub. In order to propose or object to a naming standard you must first take a drink. Traditionally the oldest member of the team starts the meeting by proposing Hungarian Notation.